# как в Entity Framework не допустить запись дубликатов?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Я получил от сайта JSON ответ. В ответе приходит 100 последних операций, которые в дальнейшем складываю в MS SQL при помощи EF. Необходимо не вставлять в БД дубликаты

```
class RootObject: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BTCUSD> BTC_USD { get; set; }
}
public class BTCUSD
{

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int trade_id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public List<BTCUSD> BTC_USD { get; set; }
}
```

//код для добавления в БД

```
 private void AddBase(Test data)
        {
            using (RootObject db = new RootObject())
            {
                foreach (var set in data.BTC_USD)
                {
                    set.id = 1;
                    db.BTC_USD.Add(set);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

            }
        }
```

Поле id, оно не существует в JSON, а просто добавлено мной в класс. Сделал по причине того, чтобы не потерять значения в trade_id(которые уникальны).
Спрашивал на форуме как мне реализовать чтобы в БД складывались только уникальные записи, посоветовали использовать триггеры INSTEAD OF INSERT.
Я попробовал создать такой триггер

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[New_Insert]
ON [dbo].[BTCUSDs] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT P.id, I.id FROM BTCUSDs P, inserted I
                WHERE P.trade_id = I.trade_id))
                INSERT INTO BTCUSDs
                SELECT trade_id, type, quantity,price,amount,date
                FROM inserted
                WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()


END
```

программа вылетает с ошибкой. Удаляю триггер, программа запускается и в БД складываются дубликаты.

Comment: Дубликаты приходят в наборе? Или это двоятся строчки из набора?

Comment: а можно проверку на уникальность возложить на бд, делаем Index по необходимому нам полю/полям которое должно быть уникально при попытке добавить запись с существующим индексом возникнет исключение, ну и просто индекс имеет смысл делать для полей по которым будет осуществляться поиск

Comment: @Dmitry, да, приходят в наборе, последние 100 действий.

Comment: @ДмитрийАзаревич, ну тогда мой ответ именно для вас, попробуйте. там еще и проверочка на то, что действия не задваиваются

Answer (score 1):

код добавления записий в базу лучше бы заменить на такой:

```
private void AddBase(Test data)
{
   using (RootObject db = new RootObject())
   {
      // Компаратор нам нужен для того, чтоб выкинуть из входящего набора
      // записи с одинаковыми trade_id, если таковые вдруг есть.
      var comparer = new BtcComparer();
      foreach (var set in data.BTC_USD.Distinct(comparer))
      {
          // Id выставлять необходимости нет, он у вас и так ключь, проставится сам
          // set.id = 1;
          db.BTC_USD.Add(set);
          // Нет необходимости сохранять каждый раз отдельную строчку
          // сохраним после добавления всех строчек
          //db.SaveChanges();
      }
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Описание компаратора

```
public class BtcComparer : IEqualityComparer<BTCUSD>
{
    public bool Equals(BTCUSD x, BTCUSD y)
    {
       return x.trade_id == y.trade_id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(BTCUSD obj)
    {
       return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Выскакивает. An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: @ДмитрийАзаревич и что там пишут в Inner Exception?

Comment: оказывается стоял уникальный ключ на поле trade_id. Я его удалил из БД. Вызываю программу, успешно компилируется, но в базу данных опять складываются дубликаты.

Comment: @ДмитрийАзаревич проверте входящие данные, не должно быть дубликатов

Comment: Суть в том, что в ответе от сервера могут быть дубликаты, но в БД надо положить уникальные записи.

Comment: @ДмитрийАзаревич для этого и есть компаратор. Его можно переделать как душе угодно

Comment: Простите, но никак не могу прикрутить этот код к своей проблеме. Объект comparer у меня всегда пустой. Как сравнивать?